# Need British Siri & date formats, but US Google. Possible?

Tags: ios

I'm a Brit living in the USA. I use the UK English Siri so that he understands my accent. I also like dd/mm/yy dates. I'd like to have my iPhone default to USA Google though, since that's where I am. UK-specific results aren't much use to me over here.

As far as I can tell, it's all keyed off the Region Format setting. By setting Region Format to United States I get USA Google searches - correct. I can then override Voice Control back to UK English and I get my butler, Mr. Siri - also good. Problem is I'm stuck with mm/dd/yy date format - confusing.

Is there a way to force USA search results in Safari without changing other region settings?